# write ANTLR regex when declaring variables list

Tags: python, regex, antlr, antlr4

I've wrote a grammar rule for a language in ANTLR as below:

```
variable: idlist COLON type (EQUAL explist)? SEMI;
idlist: identifier (COMMA identifier)*;
explist: exp (COMMA exp)*;

COLON: ':';
EQUAL: '=';
SEMI: ';';
COMMA: ',';
```

This input is valid for above grammar:

```
a, b, c: integer = 3, 4, 6;
```

But now if I want this input:

```
a, b, c, d: integer = 3, 4, 6;
```

or this:

```
a, b, c: integer = 3, 4, 6, 1;
```

becomes invalid due to inequality between amount of ID in *idlist* and value in *explist*, how I rewrite my grammar? Tks

Comment: Easy. Use a "pumping" form of "variable". Try this: `grammar Foo; variable: var_ ';' EOF; var_ : identifier var2 exp ; var2: ',' identifier var2 exp ',' | type_info ; type_info : ':' type '='; identifier: Id; Id: [a-zA-Z_]+; type: Id; exp: Num; Num: [0-9]+; WS: [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip;`. Make sure to use full grammars and examples in questions. In Antlr, make sure to use an EOF-terminated start rule.

Answer (score 3):

Don't let your grammar handle this semantic task. The syntax is correct in all those cases. The constraint that the number of left-hand-values and right-hand-values must be equal is a semantic rule you should enforce in the  semantic phase, following the parse step (the syntactic phase). This is usually done by evaluating the generated parse tree.

Comment: but if we are forced to write that, how do we write?

Comment: @DuyDuy that is not possible other than manually writing `1 id + 1 exp`, `2 ids + 2 exp`, `3 ids + 3 exp`, ...

Comment: @BartKiers there is a way to write it in ANTLR, yet I cannot find

Comment: @DuyDuy, no, you are wrong, there is no generic way to define an X amount of ids with an equal X amount of expressions in an ANTLR grammar. You could do something with a predicate, but you cannot do it in plain ANTLR syntax.

Comment: @BartKiers do you know how to replicate a group of tokens n times, if we write regex in ANTLR?

Comment: @DuyDuy something resembling regex are only available in lexer rules, not in parser rules. Like I mentioned before: what you want to do is not possible in the grammar.

Comment: @BartKiers There is a way to do it, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the previous answer that the proper way to do it would be later during the evaluation of the generated parse tree/AST.

But if you insist, here is an example of the grammar which matches the number of declarations and initializations. Please note that it is more an exercise in demonstrating the power of context-free grammar than something I would be glad to find in the production code.

```
grammar Test;

list: IDENTIFIER middle  exp ';';

middle :
   | ',' IDENTIFIER middle exp ','
   | ':' type '='
;

exp:
   NUMBER
;

type:
    IDENTIFIER
;

NUMBER : [0-9]+;
IDENTIFIER : [a-z]+;
COLON: ':';
EQUAL: '=';
SEMI: ';';
COMMA: ',';
```

In case you have a mismatch in the list sizes the error message is confusing:

```
line 1:11 mismatched input ',' expecting ';'
```

This is why I would not recommend using this approach.

Comment: Haha, yes, you're right. But now you also extend your answer by telling the OP how they can easily match each identifier to their corresponding expression in this horribly (recursive) generated parse tree  (nevertheless, +1 for the "horrible" solution :))

Comment: This is a good answer. It is difficult to determine which token(s) is basic case in recursion to write the rule